# Inserting to Numeric field using prepared statement

Tags: java, sql-server, prepared-statement

I try to insert a value to an SQL server Numeric field using a prepared statment:

```
int temp = 5;
type = java.sql.Types.NUMERIC;                      
System.out.println(temp);
prd.setObject(i+1, temp,type);
```

But this gives me a `"Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric"`.

I also tried to convert the int to a Number Or inserting it using `prd.setInt`, but this also doesn't work.

What is the right way to set a value in a prepared statement, which will be inserted successfuly in an SQL server Numeric field?

Comment: Try `BigDecimal` - pretty sure that that's the correct class, but it's more like a good guess then a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that when you convert String to int, the conversion for some reason doesn't work when trying to insert to the prepared statement.

```
int temp= 2;
type = java.sql.Types.NUMERIC;                      
System.out.println(temp);
prd.setObject(i+1, temp,type);
```

that works.

On my initial code i did: Integer.parseInt(String_value) and that for some reason ruined the variable.